# Perturbation on sequences and their limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, perturbation-theory

I believe this is really simple, but I can't figure it out alone. Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and be a sequence such that $\|x_k\|\to \infty$, and let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary.

> Is the set of limit points of $\left\{ \frac{x_k}{\left\|v+x_k\right\|} \right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ equal to the set of limit points of $\left\{ \frac{x_k}{\left\|x_k\right\|} \right\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$?

It looks true, because $v$ is a finite perturbation and everything tells me that $x_k$ is going to lead the convergence since it diverges, but I couldn't give formal arguments for proving that. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to show two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ have the same limit points, then it suffices to show that $\|a_n - b_n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. If we have a limit point $L$ of $(a_n)$, then we have a subsequence $a_{n_k} \to L$. Then,
$$\|b_{n_k} - L\| \le \|b_{n_k} - a_{n_k}\| + \|a_{n_k} - L\| \to 0 + 0,$$
since $\|b_{n_k} - a_{n_k}\|$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $\|a_n - b_n\|$ and $\|a_{n_k} - L\| \to 0$. It follows that $b_{n_k} \to L$. So, every limit point of $(a_n)$ is a limit point of $(b_n)$. Symmetrically, we can reverse the roles of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ to obtain the reverse inclusion, i.e. the limit points of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are the same.

Thus, it suffices to show that
$$\left\|\frac{x_k}{\|v + x_k\|} - \frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|}\right\| \to 0.$$
Consider:
\begin{align*}
\left\|\frac{x_k}{\|v + x_k\|} - \frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|}\right\| &= \|x_k\|\left|\frac{1}{\|v + x_k\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_k\|}\right| \\
&= \|x_k\|\frac{\Big|\|x_k\| - \|v + x_k\|\Big|}{\|v + x_k\|\|x_k\|} \\
&\le \frac{\|v\|}{\|v + x_k\|} \\
&\le \frac{\|v\|}{\|x_k\|- \|v\|} \to 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you please explain the first equation?

Comment: @Myth I've made an edit. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Sorry, the part I didn't understand is the one you took $\|x_k\|$ outside of the norm. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: I actually took the scalar $\frac{1}{\|v + x_k\|} - \frac{1}{\|x_k\|}$ out of the norm, leaving only the vector $x_k$ in the norm. The vector we're norming is that multiple of $x_k$.

Comment: Ohhh, I feel stupid, but that's good haha. Thank you so much!